# Capitalizing words in (Python)?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, capitalization

I was trying to write something to capitalize each word in a sentence. And it works fine, as follows:

```
print " ".join((word.capitalize() for word in raw_input().strip().split(" ")))
```

If the input is 'hello world', the output would be :

```
    Hello World
```

But I tried writing it differently as follows :

```
s = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
for word in s:
    word.capitalize()
print ' '.join(s)
```

And its output would be wrong :

```
    hello world
```

So what's wrong with that, why the result isn't the same ?! Thank you.

Comment: In your second program, you capitalize a copy of a word from s. Not the words in s itself.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so the string methods can't modify the original string, they always return a new string. Your 2nd code snippet isn't saving that new string. BTW, there's a simpler way to capitalize every word in a string: use the `str.title` method, eg `'hello world'.title()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is that strings are immutable and you are trying to mutate it. So if you wont to work with loop you have to create new variable.

```
s = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
new_s = ''
for word in s:
    new_s += s.capitalize()
print new_s
```

Or, It would work if you use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate over list and update `s`:

```
s = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
for index, word in enumerate(s):
    s[index] = .capitalize()
print ' '.join(s)
```

But the best way to capitalize words in string is to use [str.title()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)  - method for capitalization of words in string:

```
s = 'hello word'
print(s.title())
```

Comment: I tried it. But it would capitalize words starting with numbers (like : 3g), and I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are `immutable` and you are trying to update the same value which is not poassible.

Create a new string and update in that way.

```
s = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
st = ''
for word in s:
    st+= word.replace(word,word.capitalize())
print ''.join(st)
```

Or

```
print " ".join([i.capitalize() for i in raw_input().strip().split(" ")])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ' '.join([i.capitalize() for i in raw_input('Enter text here:').split(' ')])
```

This will solve you problem.